# How to make div float down?

Tags: html, styles

I'm making a website for my french homework (don't ask) and have encountered a problem. I'm using styles on my divs which have background images, so they're like images that are controlled. Without using absolute positioning, how do I make the div float to the bottom right hand corner of the screen?

Comment: Please, put your snippet on jsfiddle.net and edit your question with it

Comment: A place to create js, html and css snippets and share with other guys to help you.

Comment: There I can show you your code working. You can put here, but there I and you can test the code, rendering it

Comment: Is this what you want > [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KDsWj/) ?

Comment: because the images in question are saved on my hard drive it wouldnt work :/

Answer (score 0):

You said you dont want to use:

```
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
```

I guess you dont want to use this also ?

```
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
```

Comment: hmm i only didnt want to use absolute positioning because it changed the position when i tried it on a different machine. What is position:fixed?

Comment: Position fixed means that when the element is stucked there, event if you scroll up/down or left-right, he is still there. Try it !

Comment: If u presume I dont want to use that either, why did you put it in an answer?

Comment: because when i write an answere, i dont have in mind that i will help only you, i think about others who land on this page, and mabey for them the answere is helpfull....you thought much to ask this quesiton?